# Login en angular funciona para la primera request pero para las restantes hay que volverse a loguear

Tags: angular, login, jwt, headers

de antemano agradezco la ayuda, estoy armando un front en Angular y una API en springboot.
El problema es que cuando hago el login, la API me devuelve el Token y lo agrega al Headers de la primera request que haga después del login.
Pero aca comienza el problema, al hacer otra request me da error porque no le agrega el Header, para que lo haga debo volver a loguearme.
Arme un servicio para realizar el inicio, al que inyecto en el componente del login.
En caso de que se logue correctamente es redirigido a otro componente donde puede hacer el CRUD de la informacion.

Este es el servicio

```
introducir el código aquí

    @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InicioService {


  Url="http://localhost:8080/api/login"
  currentUserSubjet: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    console.log("el servicio de autenticación esta corriendo");
    this.currentUserSubjet= new BehaviorSubject<any>(JSON.stringify(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser')|| '{}'));
    console.log(this.currentUserSubjet.value);
  }
  IniciarSesion(credenciales:any):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.Url,credenciales).pipe(map(data => {
      sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(data));
      this.currentUserSubjet.next(data);
      console.log(this.currentUserSubjet.value);
      return data;
          } ))
  }


y el ts del componente

       `export class InicioComponent implements OnInit {
       opcion:number =2;
    
      iniformu:FormGroup
      constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder, private inicioService:InicioService, private ruta:Router) {
        this.iniformu=this.formBuilder.group(
          {
            mail:[''],
            contraseña:[''],
            headers: {
                      'Accept':'aplication/json',
                      'Content-Type':'aplication/json',
                     }
          }
        );
    
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    
      get Correo() {
        return this.iniformu.get('mail');
      }
      get Contraseña() {
        return this.iniformu.get('contraseña');
      }
      onIniciar(event:Event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.inicioService.IniciarSesion(this.iniformu.value).subscribe(data =>
         { //console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
          this.ruta.navigate(['/edit']);
          //console.log(this.inicioService.usuarioAutenticadoToken);
    
         })
      }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo una duda. En el codigo que copias del componente no le veo el decorador

```
@Component({})
```

El problema es que no estas guardando el token en ningun lado y debes pasarselo al header en cada request. Para solucionarlo debes implementar un *interceptor*. Sirve para obtener la request justo antes de enviarla, en este proceso le debes incluir el token a la peticion

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  
    const token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');

    let request = req;

    if (token) {
      request = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          authorization: `Bearer ${ token }`
        }
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

Este codigo es de este [articulo](https://medium.com/@insomniocode/angular-autenticaci%C3%B3n-usando-interceptors-a26c167270f4)

[Aqui puedes leer en la Doc oficial de Angular](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)

Espero que te ayude !

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema lo tenia en el interceptor.